# Exchange 2013 Uninstall Issue - "Exchange Server Error: An Incomplete Installation Was Detected"

Tags: exchange

I have some problems uninstalling MSFT Exchange 2013. First, I'tried to uninstall it using the Add/Remove Programs but that failed half way through.

Now I'm trying to use:

```
setup.exe /m:uninstall
```

I am receiving following message:

```
Welcome to Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 Unattended Setup
Mailbox role: Mailbox service
Mailbox role: Unified Messaging service
Mailbox role: Client Access service
Mailbox role: Transport service
Client Access role: Front End Transport service
Management tools
Client Access role: Client Access Front End service
Languages

Performing Microsoft Exchange Server Prerequisite Check

    Configuring Prerequisites                                 COMPLETED
    Prerequisite Analysis                                     COMPLETED

Configuring Microsoft Exchange Server

    Preparing Setup                                           COMPLETED
    Mailbox role: Client Access service                       FAILED
     The following error was generated when "$error.Clear();
          $CommandAppCmd = join-path $env:SystemRoot System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe
;
          Start-SetupProcess -Name "$CommandAppCmd" -args "delete app /app.name:
`"Exchange Back End/mapi/nspi`"";
          Start-SetupProcess -Name "$CommandAppCmd" -args "delete appPool /appPo
ol.name:MSExchangeMapiAddressBookAppPool";
        " was run: "Process execution failed with exit code 50.".

     The following error was generated when "$error.Clear();
          $CommandAppCmd = join-path $env:SystemRoot System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe
;
          Start-SetupProcess -Name "$CommandAppCmd" -args "delete app /app.name:
`"Exchange Back End/mapi/nspi`"";
          Start-SetupProcess -Name "$CommandAppCmd" -args "delete appPool /appPo
ol.name:MSExchangeMapiAddressBookAppPool";
        " was run: "Process execution failed with exit code 1168.".


The Exchange Server setup operation didn't complete. More details can be found
in ExchangeSetup.log located in the <SystemDrive>:\ExchangeSetupLogs folder.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the StackExchange world. Please keep noted that StackOverflow is a developer community while your question would better be moved to ServerFault, the admin community. I will inform an moderator so that this question is hopefully moved to the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

The error "1168" is mostly a general error (see [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ehlro/2010/11/21/setup-for-exchange-2010-service-pack-1-failing-with-process-execution-failed-with-exit-code-1168/)), however from your posting I would say that this error might happen because of the reason that some webservices aren´t working correctly, so the setup isn´t able to remove them. The best offer I could give you here would be to re-create them as explained [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/get-exchangehelp/2013/02/07/managing-exchange-2013-iis-virtual-directories-web-applications/), then re-run the uninstaller.

*P.S. Keep noted that you should make sure that you uninstall exchange fully, otherwiese some elements might remain in your exchange environment and might cause issues.*